# Minimum requirements on a function to prove injectivity

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have one predicate and two finite sets A and B.

$$\mathbf{ \text{I(x): x is an injective function.}}$$

From these I construct the quantified statement:

$$\mathbf{ \forall x\in\text{U:[ I(x)]}}$$

$$\mathbf{ \text{U = \{ f is a function | f: A}\mapsto}\text{B\}}$$

What assumptions do I need to make on each of the sets to make each of the quantified statements true?

The answers in my book says the first statement is true when |A| = 0, |A| = 1, or |B| = 0, though I'm not sure I follow the logic.

If |A| = 0 then I can see that the statement is true in regards to the only function being the empty function which I've read is injective (though haven´t understood exactly why yet).

But if |A| = 1, how can I assume f(x) will have an inverse without making any assumptions about B?

Also if |B| = 0, is this statement just vacuously true with regards to injectivity?

Comment: Warning: unclear if I am correctly interpreting the question.  The only way to demonstrate that injectivity is violated is to provide a counter example that involves two distinct elements in the domain of the function.  Therefore, if there is only one element in the function's domain, such a demonstration is not possible.

Comment: Your use of MathJax is a bit weird. Why do you put a lot of math stuff inside `\text{...}`? That command should only be used for text inside math, e.g. `$$S(x): x \text{ is an injective function}$$` producing
$$S(x): x \text{ is an injective function}$$
You should also use math mode in running text, e.g. `$|A|=1$` to get $|A|=1$.

Comment: For $f : A \to B$ use `f : A \to B`. The `\mapsto` symbol ($\mapsto$) is used to produce a function, e.g. $x \mapsto x^2+3x-4$ ($\lambda$-expressions in programming).

Comment: Shouldn't $I(x)$ be $S(x)$ (or the other way around)?

Comment: If $|B|=0$, then there is a function $f\colon A\to B$ only if $A=\emptyset$ and the empty function $\emptyset\to\emptyset$ is obviously injective. You need *two* elements to disprove injectivity, and the empty set has none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f$ is injective if $x \neq y \Rightarrow f(x) \neq f(y)$.  So if $\operatorname{dom}(f)=A$ and $\vert A \vert \leq 1$, then $f$ must always be injective because you can never have $x, y \in A$ with $x \neq y$ so the implication is vacuously true.